# How to track down the code during debugging?

Tags: neovim, error, line-numbers

The problem I'm trying to troubleshoot now is specific to recent neovim 0.5.0 (exact version I'm using is `NVIM v0.5.0-ef3230f35` but this issue reproduces in the same way on all my machines each running slightly different recent nvim).

The problem does not occur in vim.

It shows like this:

```
Error detected while processing function 9[30]..<SNR>30_callback:
line   21:
Vim(let):E730: using List as a String
```

Now I know that `<SNR>30` means that I can look up the script the failure is occurring in `:scriptnames`, however I really kind of still need a line number. The line 21 is not right because the file corresponding to 30 (which is definitely the right script) has a comment at the top of it that is far longer than 21 lines...

So I'm curious if I can extract any meaning out of `9[30]` or `_callback`. And perhaps line 21 is relative to something. Possibly it's an offset into some callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find that the 21st line inside of a function named `s:callback` in the file referenced by `<SNR>30` (in my case fzf.vim) is where the error is being thrown (the code is `echoerr v:exception`).

Comment: Yes, `s:func` becomes `<SNR>..._func`. The line is relative to the start of that function.

Comment: Yep, and this was my saga https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/issues/1199